# URL to reflect ajax loaded Wordpress post permalink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, url

I have Next & Prev buttons that load posts through ajax into a div.
My js to do this works perfectly except that when the new post loads its permalink is not reflected in the address bar. Only the first loaded url of the page stays throughout.

What do I add to my existing code to make sure the address bar changes along with each Wordpress post?

Current JS:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#main-content').on('click', '.page a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#main-content').html('<h4>loading</h4>').load(url+ ' #main-content');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your ajax function should be handeling this. Please share your Ajax function.

Comment: This is all I have for now

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [html5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) adding the url you want via [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method)

something like

```
var stateObj = { state: 'somestate' };
history.pushState(stateObj, 'unused state', your_localized.permalink);
```